# How to freeze the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, how can I freeze the screen in one scene, change scene, and then unfreeze it in the other scene? With freezing the screen I simply mean that it doesn't get updated while it's frozen. With screen I simply mean this: [image: https://i.gyazo.com/10f8673d28da776c064fbb0e716866ad.jpg]

I've tried to set Time.timeScale = 0, but that didn't work.

The thing is that I have different screen orientations in the scenes: portrait in the first and landscape in the other. This causes the second scene to twist/ruin the loading screen that was loaded in the first scene. The stuff being initialized in the second scene demands landscape orientation, so I can't just change the screen orientation after everything have been initialized.

I just want to freeze the screen after the loading image has loaded and then unfreeze it after the second scene has been initialized. Is this possible?

This is my code at the moment, generalized:

```
// Script for the first scene
class firstClass(){
    IEnumerator ChangeScene(){
        // Display loading screen in portrait orientation
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        // Load the second scene
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("secondScene");
    }
}

// Script for the second scene
class secondClass(){
     Start(){
         Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft; // twists the loading screen :(
         Init(a lot of stuff) // Needs landscape orientation to be initialized properly

         // Init done, hide loading screen
         loadingScreen.SetActive(false);

     }
}
```

This is how I want it to work:

```
class firstClass(){
    IEnumerator ChangeScene(){
        // Display loading screen in portrait orientation
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        FreezeScreen();
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("secondScene");
    }
}

class secondClass(){
     Start(){
         Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft; // doesn't affect the loading screen because the screen is frozen!
         Init(a lot of stuff);
         UnfreezeScreen();
         // Init done, hide loading screen
         loadingScreen.SetActive(false);

     }
}
```

Here's an illustration:
https://gyazo.com/864303465be750b7970636415ddf070d

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? You mean make orientation to stay the-same and not change?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the displayed things on the screen to stay the same even if i change the screen orientation.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you mean by "freeze" the screen.  You will have to remove that word.  Could it be you want to ***disable rotation*** perhaps during your loading process, and only ***enable rotation*** later?

Comment: Note that regarding ***pausing a game***. This is ***very hard indeed***.  Very, very difficult.  On large games there are whole teams of engineers that do nothing other than write the pause states for everything in the game.  Note that there is utterly no way to "freeze" the "screen" in Unity.  "screen" is meaningless.  If you mean "freeze" every GameObject in the scene, there is utterly no way conceptually to do that.  You have to write pause states for every single thing in the game.

Answer (score 0):

```
void freezeOrientation(bool freezeOrnt = true)
{
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft = freezeOrnt;
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeRight = freezeOrnt;
    Screen.autorotateToPortrait = freezeOrnt;
    Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown = freezeOrnt;
}
```

Freeze Orientation

```
freezeOrientation(true);
```

Un-freeze Orientation

```
freezeOrientation(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope, it didn't work. I think my problem is more defined now, check my edit

Comment: **"I think my problem is more defined now**" I don't think so. I changed the title to make sense then you changed it back to something that doesn't make sense. The updated code you have in your question does not look like the code in my answer. Until you update your code to reflect what's in my answer, I can't tell what you are doing wrong. All my code is doing is disabling rotation is all orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lines below in your `Start()` or `Awake()` on an active object in the scenes that need orientation modification. Choose any of the lines regarding your intended orientation

```
void Awake()
{
 Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
 //OR
 Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait; 
}
```

As these are logical orientations so touch coordinates change as well with current orientation.

You need to modify your second class start so that it goes landscape after initialization and disabling loading scene.

```
class secondClass(){
void Start()
{ 
         Init(a lot of stuff);

         // Init done, hide loading screen
         loadingScreen.SetActive(false);

         Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As truly this is expected behavior not only in unity, but in any game engine.

Why I think so?
When you load another scene -- old scene must be destroyed :) As it's takes lot of resources :)

As I think, you need to save all info about objects settings on the scene. Load another scene. Do what do you need. And switch back to this scene and restore from settings.

or to ask your question by another way: tell about expected result and ask how to do this better :)