# Portrait mode for Phones/Tablets and Landscape mode for Android TV?

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine

My app has been designed to use portrait mode in phones and tablets. I'm trying to support Android TV which requires landscape mode, so my app is now using different layouts based on whether the device is Android TV or not.

The problem is that Google rejects apps from Android TV that use the "portrait" feature. How can I keep "portrait" for phones/tablets and switch to landscape only for TV with the same APK? Is the only way to do this to make two different APKs? I'd like to avoid this if possible.

PS. I'm using Unity 3D which might limit some of the more obscure solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the screen mode from code based on whether the device is a phone/tablet or TV.

First step is to check if this app is running on a TV or mobile device.There is no official API to do this on Android but [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-tv-detection.295965/) post describes how to do that as a plugin with [`AndroidJavaClass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html).

```
bool isAndroidTv()
{
    #if !UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_EDITOR
    return false;
    #else

    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject androidActivity = unityPlayerJavaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaClass contextJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Context");
    AndroidJavaObject modeServiceConst = contextJavaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("UI_MODE_SERVICE");
    AndroidJavaObject uiModeManager = androidActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", modeServiceConst);
    int currentModeType = uiModeManager.Call<int>("getCurrentModeType");
    AndroidJavaClass configurationAndroidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.res.Configuration");
    int modeTypeTelevisionConst = configurationAndroidClass.GetStatic<int>("UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION");

    return (modeTypeTelevisionConst == currentModeType);
    #endif
}
```

Then you can change the screen orientation with [`Screen.orientation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html), in the `Awake` function:

```
void Awake()
{
    bool androidTv = isAndroidTv();
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeLeft = androidTv;
    Screen.autorotateToLandscapeRight = false;
    Screen.autorotateToPortrait = !androidTv;
    Screen.autorotateToPortraitUpsideDown = false;

    if (androidTv)
    {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

You can use this in a "game controller" object that is set up to run early through the script order settings.

Also, you'll want to set the Android player settings to have the Default Orientation set to Auto Rotation.

Comment: Does this require setting the "default orientation" to Auto in the player settings? If so, will the phone change the orientation when the user rotates their phone?

Comment: **"Does this require setting the "default orientation" to Auto in the player settings?"** I am not sure about that. You can test it right away with an Android device to see what happens. **"If so, will the phone change the orientation when the user rotates their phone?"** Again, you have to try it to see if it changes when user rotates their phone. If that happens, you can use my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38790423/3785314) to solve that problem. Just call that function after setting the orientation.

Comment: Good. Does it change orientation when the user rotates their phone?

Comment: No, it doesn't, if I set those autorotateToLandscapeLeft properties to false.

Comment: Good to know. Happy coding!

Comment: Update: With Unity 5.5.2, the Unity splash screen is displaying in landscape in mobile devices, then switches to portrait when that script is executed in my first scene. Any idea how to fix that?